# How to Compare current row with Next Row - LEAD

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to compare current row with next row from the different table. Am able to achieve first two condition but not able to fix the 3rd condition. Pls refer the table and the required out put in the given screenshot.

1. RE.ManageAccountID = CL.ManageAccountID
2. CL.ChangeDt > RE.ExpireDt
3. **CL.ChangeDt < Next row RE.ReleaseDt**
   [image]

Comment: If you upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server (which I strongly recommend you do, 2008 has been out of support for almost a year now) you can do this very easily by using `LEAD` and `LAG`.

Comment: can you pls help me with LEAD query if possible for the above example, as am not good with the SQL

Comment: Why do you want LEAD? It isn't available in 2008. Are the tags wrong?

Comment: Right I should have tag to 2012.LEAD and LAG is supported in my environment

Comment: have you looked at the docs? It is pretty simple then. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Am already using ROW_NUMBER() method to get the first row for the first two condition match, is it good idea to add LEAD for the 3rd condition, which again quite similar to ROW_NUMBER() method.

Comment: If you are using `LEAD`/`LAG` there's no need for `ROW_NUMBER` and a CTE/sub query. Put your attempt(s) using `LEAD`/`LAG` in your question by using the [edit] feature if they aren't working, and explain why it isn't working, so that we can help you.